# Is it "offshoot of" or "offshoot from"?

Tags: word-choice

The research I've done online shows about a 60/40 split in favor of "offshoot of" rather than "offshoot from". Is it just a matter of style, long-term usage, or is there a grammatical rule? I need to know which expression to use, because I am writing a very formal cover letter for my resume. I am applying for a coveted position in a large publishing house. I have been told by a good friend of mine, who is employed there, that the company typically receive scores of applications for that position. So even the most picayune error is reason enough for a letter, and its author, to be rejected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both form are acceptable and can often be used interchangeably,  Google books shows a wider use of "offshoot of" vs "offshoot from": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=offshoot+from%2C+offshoot+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coffshoot%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coffshoot%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Can you include a sample sentence in your question please?  As ever, context is everything.

Answer (score 1):

As Josh61 notes in his comment, the difference in frequency of usage between "offshoot of" (blue line in the chart below, which covers the period 1800–2005) and "offshoot from" (red line) has been been quite large for more than a century and shows no signs of disappearing:

[image]

Two hundred years ago, neither expression was at all common, but today usage is strongly on the side of "offshoot of." Even so, it would be misleading to suggest that usage of "offshoot from" is extraordinarily rare or highly unusual. The Google Books search results beneath the graph in Josh61's linked graph list 95 matches for "offshoot from" for the period 1962–2005.

On the other hand those same search results list more than 400 matches for "offshoot of" for the period 1990–2005—so you're looking at 95 matches over 44 years versus 400+ matches over 15 years. It's not a close contest.